# How to delete data based on time interval

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I  have a table in my database.The table has a field VehId(Int) and trackdt(Datetime)

My table has 3000 billion rows(yes, that's right 3000 billion). so i want to delete old data. but i want to delete data based on time interval.

I want to delete records of every 20 seconds for each vehicle.

Below is the table I have

```
VehId  Trackdt
1      2017-05-20 00:00:30.000
2      2017-05-20 00:00:32.000         
2      2017-05-20 00:00:42.000
1      2017-05-20 00:00:40.000
2      2017-05-20 00:00:52.000
1      2017-05-20 00:00:50.000
1      2017-05-20 00:01:00.000
2      2017-05-20 00:01:02.000
1      2017-05-20 00:01:10.000
1      2017-05-20 00:01:20.000
2      2017-05-20 00:01:12.000
1      2017-05-20 00:01:30.000
2      2017-05-20 00:01:22.000
2      2017-05-20 00:01:32.000
```

After delete data should be like below

```
VehId  TRackdt
1      2017-05-20 00:00:30.000
2      2017-05-20 00:00:32.000
1      2017-05-20 00:01:00.000
2      2017-05-20 00:01:02.000
1      2017-05-20 00:01:30.000
2      2017-05-20 00:01:32.000
```

I tried below query but it is taking too much time

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DELETEINTERVALDATA]

@FROMDATE DATETIME,
@TODATE DATETIME,
@INTERVAL INT,
@FLAG INT

AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TRACKDT DATETIME
DECLARE @I INT =1
DECLARE @V INT =1
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @VCOUNT INT
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = ''
DECLARE @VEHID INT
DECLARE @TIMEDIFF INT


 CREATE TABLE #TEMPVEHICLE
 (
    SNO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    VEHID INT
 )

 CREATE TABLE #TEMPLOG
 (
    SNO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TRACKDT DATETIME
 )

 IF (@FLAG = 1 )
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #TEMPVEHICLE (VEHID) SELECT VEHID FROM VEHICLEMASTER ORDER BY VEHID         

        SELECT @VCOUNT = COUNT(SNO) FROM #TEMPVEHICLE 

        WHILE (@V <= @VCOUNT) 
            BEGIN               

                SELECT @VEHID = VEHID FROM #TEMPVEHICLE WHERE SNO = @V

                INSERT INTO #TEMPLOG(TRACKDT) SELECT TRACKDT 
                FROM TRACKINGLOG WITH(NOLOCK)
                WHERE TRACKDT BETWEEN @FROMDATE AND @TODATE AND VEHID = @VEHID
                ORDER BY TRACKDT ASC

                SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(SNO) FROM #TEMPLOG 

                WHILE (@I <= @COUNT)
                    BEGIN                           
                        SELECT @TRACKDT=TRACKDT FROM #TEMPLOG WHERE SNO = @I                            
                        IF (@I = 1)
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @STARTDATE = @TRACKDT
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @TIMEDIFF = DATEDIFF(SECOND,@STARTDATE,@TRACKDT)
                                IF @TIMEDIFF <= 20
                                    BEGIN
                                        DELETE FROM TRACKINGLOG WHERE TRACKDT = @TRACKDT AND VEHID = @VEHID                                         
                                    END
                                ELSE
                                    BEGIN
                                        SELECT @STARTDATE = @TRACKDT
                                    END
                            END
                        SELECT  @I = @I + 1
                    END
                TRUNCATE TABLE #TEMPLOG
                SELECT  @V = @V + 1,@STARTDATE= '',@I=1
            END
        DROP TABLE #TEMPLOG
        DROP TABLE #TEMPVEHICLE
    END
   END
```

How can I write query which delete data based on time interval and should be quick??

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to retain the minimum and maximum `trackdt` per `vehid`? Also, what is the exact table definition, including indexes?

Comment: No no no I've updated my question.. i want data of each vehicle of interval of minimum 20 seconds. Table has ID column which is PK so you can count that as index i guess.

Comment: @user2928116 : try my query. I hope your SP is correct.

Comment: You are saying less than 20 seconds, but you deleted 2017-05-20 00:00:50.000 which is equal to 20 seconds. Don't you mean less or equal?

Comment: Sorry for that I meant less or equal

Comment: @user2928116 your desired output corresponds to a *30* second interval, not 20

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually not 30 if difference is 21 seconds, i dont want to delete it

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output corresponds to a *30* second interval.

You can retrieve previous values in a result set using window functions. For example, LAG(trackdt,1) will return the previous value. `LEAD` the next. `FIRST_VALUE` will return the first value in a set.

The query :

```
select * ,
    FIRST_VALUE(trackdt) over (partition by vehid order by trackdt) as t0
from @mytable
```

Will return the first `trackdt` value per vehicle, when the rows are ordered by `trackdt`.

```
1   2017-05-20 00:00:30.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000
1   2017-05-20 00:00:40.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000
1   2017-05-20 00:00:50.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000
```

This way we can calculate the interval between the current and first value in the partition with `datediff`. The resulting query is a bit ugly:

```
select * ,
    FIRST_VALUE(trackdt) over (partition by vehid order by trackdt) as t0,
    datediff(s,FIRST_VALUE(trackdt) over (partition by vehid order by trackdt),
               trackdt) as interval
from @mytable
```

Dividing by 30 would give us the interval bucket to which each row belongs.

```
1   2017-05-20 00:01:10.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000 1
1   2017-05-20 00:01:20.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000 1
1   2017-05-20 00:01:30.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000 2
2   2017-05-20 00:00:32.000 2017-05-20 00:00:32.000 0
2   2017-05-20 00:00:42.000 2017-05-20 00:00:32.000 0
```

Calculating the *remainder* though, would return 0 for the first row in every 30-second bucket:

```
select * ,
    FIRST_VALUE(trackdt) over (partition by vehid order by trackdt) as t0,
    datediff(s,FIRST_VALUE(trackdt) over (partition by vehid order by trackdt),
               trackdt) %30 as remainder
from @mytable

1   2017-05-20 00:01:00.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000 0
1   2017-05-20 00:01:10.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000 10
1   2017-05-20 00:01:20.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000 20
1   2017-05-20 00:01:30.000 2017-05-20 00:00:30.000 0
2   2017-05-20 00:00:32.000 2017-05-20 00:00:32.000 0
```

We can use one or more CTEs to tidy-up this query and perform the deletion:

```
with start_times as
(
    select * ,
        FIRST_VALUE(trackdt) over (partition by vehid order by trackdt) as t0
    from @mytable
),
intervals as
(
    select * ,
        datediff(s,t0,trackdt) %30 as rem
    from start_times
)
delete 
from intervals
where rem<>0
```

This query depends on having values every 30 seconds.

In general, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to identify records within an interval bucket and simply pick the first row in a bucket. Since we want to *retain* the first row, we pick anything that has a ROW_NUMBER>1:

```
with start_times as
(
    select * ,
        FIRST_VALUE(trackdt) over (partition by vehid order by trackdt) as t0
    from #mytable
),
intervals as
(
    select * ,
        datediff(s,t0,trackdt) /30 as interval
    from start_times
),
ordered as
(
    select *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by vehid,interval order by trackdt) row_num 
    from intervals
)
select vehid,trackdt
from ordered
where row_num>1
```

Even though this query is fast, I wouldn't use it on a 3 trillion row table. Windowing often results in spooling - temporary results are stored in tempdb to allow window calculations. It would be better to select the IDs of the rows that have to be deleted, insert them into a temporary table and then use a DELETE with a join clause:

```
DELETE HugeTable
From HugeTable
    INNER JOIN TempTable on TempTable.ID=HugeTable.ID
```

Even so, you probably want to *batch* deletions. In this case you could use the [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql) function to calculate a batch number for each row between 1 and N:

```
select ID,NTILE(100) over(order by vehid,trackdt) as batch_number
from ordered
where row_num=1
```

This will calculate a batch number between 1 and 100. You can store this in the temporary table and delete one batch of rows at a time.

Comment: Trackdt will not have exactly 30 seconds difference it could be anything from 5 seconds to 60 seconds.

Comment: TIL `NTILE`. +1

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete a record if the time was 20 seconds or less after the previous time. But if the previous time gets deleted you than you want to compare with the time before that etc.
You will need some kind of loping for that. A recursive table expression or regular looping.

```
Declare @myTable table (vehid int, trackdt datetime)
insert into @mytable values
(1,      '2017-05-20 00:00:30.000'),
(2,      '2017-05-20 00:00:32.000'),         
(2,      '2017-05-20 00:00:42.000'),
(1,      '2017-05-20 00:00:40.000'),
(2,      '2017-05-20 00:00:52.000'),
(1,      '2017-05-20 00:00:50.000'),
(1,      '2017-05-20 00:01:00.000'),
(2,      '2017-05-20 00:01:02.000'),
(1,      '2017-05-20 00:01:10.000'),
(1,      '2017-05-20 00:01:20.000'),
(2,      '2017-05-20 00:01:12.000'),
(1,      '2017-05-20 00:01:30.000'),
(2,      '2017-05-20 00:01:22.000'),
(2,      '2017-05-20 00:01:32.000')

--set @@rowcount to 1
select 1

while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
begin
    DELETE T1
    from @mytable t1

    --previous time
    outer apply (select top 1 trackdt from  @mytable where vehid = t1.vehid and trackdt < t1.trackdt order by 1 desc)t2
    --previous time before that
    outer apply (select top 1 trackdt from  @mytable where vehid = t1.vehid and trackdt < t2.trackdt order by 1 desc)t3

    --previous time was less or equal to 20 seconds
    where DATEDIFF(second,t2.trackdt,t1.trackdt)<=20

    --previous time before that was more than 20 seconds or there is no time before
    and (DATEDIFF(second,t3.trackdt,t2.trackdt)>20 or t3.trackdt is null)

end

select * from @mytable
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Peter. Your query seems a little fast but it is not giving me expected output. if previous time(start time) and current time has difference less than 20 seconds then i want to delete current time then i will check difference between start time and new current time if it has difference less than 20 seconds same again current time will be deleted and if it is greater than 20 seconds my current time will become start Time and then i want to check difference of start time and next current time and so on... Hence, previous time will never be deleted.

Comment: For more info you can see my store procedure

Comment: @user2928116 It seems to be working for your sample data. Can you give an example where this query is not working properly?

Comment: @user2928116 your stored procedure is a bit... convoluted. Explain what you want to do, don't force people to reverse engineer your attempt

Answer (score 0):

With 30TBs of records it will take a week or more even with the fastest method.

You could try

1. Select and export records at intervals into CSVs - multiple batches
2. Create a new table for the new records
3. Import the CSV files with something like pg_bulkload
4. Delete the old table and rename the new one

I'd first do the first 3 steps on one 10-million-record CSV file and calculate how long it will take to move the whole thing this way

Answer (score -1):

Please read about [Parameter sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/). Assuming your stored procedure is slow BUT correct, I have updated your SP. Kindly Try :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DELETEINTERVALDATA]

@FROMDATE1 DATETIME,
@TODATE1 DATETIME,
@INTERVAL1 INT,
@FLAG1 INT

AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TRACKDT DATETIME
DECLARE @I INT =1
DECLARE @V INT =1
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @VCOUNT INT
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = ''
DECLARE @VEHID INT
DECLARE @TIMEDIFF INT

DECLARE @FROMDATE DATETIME = @FROMDATE1
DECLARE @TODATE DATETIME = @TODATE1
DECLARE @INTERVAL INT = @INTERVAL1
DECLARE @FLAG INT = @FLAG1


 CREATE TABLE #TEMPVEHICLE
 (
    SNO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    VEHID INT
 )

 CREATE TABLE #TEMPLOG
 (
    SNO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TRACKDT DATETIME
 )

 IF (@FLAG = 1 )
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #TEMPVEHICLE (VEHID) SELECT VEHID FROM VEHICLEMASTER ORDER BY VEHID         

        SELECT @VCOUNT = COUNT(SNO) FROM #TEMPVEHICLE 

        WHILE (@V <= @VCOUNT) 
            BEGIN               

                SELECT @VEHID = VEHID FROM #TEMPVEHICLE WHERE SNO = @V

                INSERT INTO #TEMPLOG(TRACKDT) SELECT TRACKDT 
                FROM TRACKINGLOG WITH(NOLOCK)
                WHERE TRACKDT BETWEEN @FROMDATE AND @TODATE AND VEHID = @VEHID
                ORDER BY TRACKDT ASC

                SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(SNO) FROM #TEMPLOG 

                WHILE (@I <= @COUNT)
                    BEGIN                           
                        SELECT @TRACKDT=TRACKDT FROM #TEMPLOG WHERE SNO = @I                            
                        IF (@I = 1)
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @STARTDATE = @TRACKDT
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @TIMEDIFF = DATEDIFF(SECOND,@STARTDATE,@TRACKDT)
                                IF @TIMEDIFF <= 20
                                    BEGIN
                                        DELETE FROM TRACKINGLOG WHERE TRACKDT = @TRACKDT AND VEHID = @VEHID                                         
                                    END
                                ELSE
                                    BEGIN
                                        SELECT @STARTDATE = @TRACKDT
                                    END
                            END
                        SELECT  @I = @I + 1
                    END
                TRUNCATE TABLE #TEMPLOG
                SELECT  @V = @V + 1,@STARTDATE= '',@I=1
            END
        DROP TABLE #TEMPLOG
        DROP TABLE #TEMPVEHICLE
    END
   END
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But It is still taking too much time. I need to delete 3000 billion rows. So i think it will take days to delete and i don't have that much time

Comment: Okay. Maybe someone else will suggest better approach. We need to divide it into time period for efficiency conceptwise.

Comment: Parameter sniffing isn't going to make a cursor *any* faster

Comment: Great @PanagiotisKanavos : maybe you can propose the solution for this problem ?

Comment: Yes. Check Peter's answer for starters. Parameter sniffing doesn't have anything to do with speeding up a cursor. *Indexing* does. Preventing full-table scans does, which means avoiding any operations on fields.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : enlighten me with a supporting document ?

Comment: @PrabhatG Books Online. All tutorials and articles. [This one from Simple Talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/the-road-to-professional-database-development-set-based-thinking/) compares both approaches and shows how a cursor is consistently 150 times slower. Comparing with previous values is easy since 2012 with windowing functions like LAG, LEAD

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : You are a great critic. I need some book or article stating "Parameter sniffing isn't going to make a cursor any faster"